# Need to upgrade/diagnose my wifi driver (Intel Wireless-AC 9560) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, iwlwifi, msi

My current problems:

- There's a problem with wifi on Ubuntu 20.04, that's not present on my Windows 10 boot. I have 30% packet loss pinging my router (~0% on windows)
- It gets worse upon plugging in my charger.
- Since it works on Windows, I suspect it's related to a driver.
- My software and updates page says that 'This device is not working'

I think I need to try upgrading my WiFi driver, or enable it if I already have the latest drivers. How do I do that?

My computer: an MSI GF63 8RC

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question - the system offered you a solution (backport-iwlwifi-dkms). You simply need to select it.

Comment: it's disabled. I cannot select it.